# What is the correct way to implement Auth/ACL in MVC?

Tags: php, object-oriented, authentication, codeigniter

I am looking into making a correctly laid out MVC Auth/ACL system. I *think* I want the authentication of a user (and the session handling) to be separate from the ACL system. (I don't know why but this seems a good idea from the things I've read.)

What does MVC have to do with this question you ask? Because I wish for the application to be well integrated with my ACL. An example of a controller (CodeIgniter):

```
<?php
class forums extends MX_Controller
{
    $allowed = array('users', 'admin');
    $need_login = true;

        function __construct()
        {
        //example of checking if logged in.
            if($this->auth->logged_in() && $this->auth->is_admin())
        {
            echo "you're logged in!";
        }
    }
    public function add_topic()
    {
        if($this->auth->allowed('add_topic')
        {
            //some add topic things.
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'not allowed to add topic';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

#### My thoughts

`$this->auth` would be autoloaded in the system.  I would like to check the `$allowed` array against the user currently (not) logged in and react accordingly.

Is this a good way of doing things? I haven't seen much literature on MVC integration and Auth. I want to make things as easy as possible.

Answer (score 4):

My approach within Zend Framework has been to have a base class of SecureController which all controllers that require authentication must extend. In the SecureController I have a pre-dispatch authentication check for whether a user is logged in else forward to the login page.

After the login check is completed, I then carry out an authorization check whether the user can access the resource and action, the controller is usually tied to a single resource (but this behavior can be overridden) and the controller action can be mapped to a resource action.

With this in place, the only thing I need to do in each child controller is map the resource and action to what is being done without ever having to invoke the security checks again.

If I need specific ACL checks especially in view generation I can use the Zend_ACL instance that is tied to the user's session

Comment: this was definitely a very popular answer when it was written, but if you're coming across this question in 2016, this stuff is mostly handled with middleware.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to come-up with my own explanations, but i found a really comprehensive post in the middle of compiling my answer. Hopefully you will find more than you asked in this post - [PHP ACL implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430181/1437962)

**Edir:** Basically, idea behind the post suggest to use  use **decorator pattern** (look at `Wiki` for more info). In simple concept this pattern recommend to take your object, and place it inside another object, which will act like a protective shell. In this way, your **code would not be required** to extend the original class.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Essential idea is added, please enjoy the reading.